# Ubuntu PPTP VPN to Buffalo Router VPN,

Tags: windows, 15.04, vpn, pptp

With my Windows laptop, I would connect via PPTP VPN, it worked fine. Now, through Ubuntu 15.04, it connects, but disconnects again after about 30 seconds.

You can see the IP that gets assigned via VPN is 172.31.148.2, on the home remote network 192.168.11.X. My local IP/network is 192.168.0.162, on 192.168.0.x.

dpkg -s network-manager-pptp >> 0.9.10.0-1ubuntu1

Any idea on where to go from here? thanks!

The settings are:

PPTP Advanced Options
checked: MSCHAP, MSCHAPv2, Use Point-to-Point encryption (MPPE) (All Available (Default)), Allow BSD data compression, Allow Deflate data compression, Use TCP header compression

unchecked: PAP, CHAP, EAP, Allow stateful encryption

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g7gh.png

[tail -f /var/log/syslog](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WMdqZmifg_nTA46O7zAGBRPEh5pcMg2CwgeTFQlxPCM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

There was an error in my syslog,

> ```
> short read (-1): Message too long
> ```

which suggested an MTU problem. Apparently, sometimes VPNs complain about incorrect MTU settings. As I connect to home via a Verizon 4G wireless card, this VPN wasn't happy, and would drop after 30 seconds of activity. Or so.

Here's what I did to fix it.

```
ping -s 1472 google.com
```

which sets the MTU (byte length) of the ping. Try out different numbers. I started lowering it drastically, jumping up and down by a couple hundred, then guessing it down to a single number, for me it was 1400, which translated to an MTU of 1428. The shell command says something to this effect

```
drew@drew-buntu-laptop:~$ ping -s 1400 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.219.196) 1400(1428) bytes of data.
72 bytes from lga25s40-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.219.196): icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 (truncated)
72 bytes from lga25s40-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.219.196): icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 (truncated)
72 bytes from lga25s40-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.219.196): icmp_seq=3 ttl=46 (truncated)
72 bytes from lga25s40-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.219.196): icmp_seq=4 ttl=46 (truncated)
```

Then to actually change the MTU setting for my connection, in the top right of the desktop (ubuntu 15.04) right click on the wifi bars > edit connections > select the wifi you're currently connected to (not the VPN), hit edit.
[image: connection properties]

Then near the bottom of that screen, you can enter in your custom MTU length.

Disconnect from wifi, reconnect, boom. VPN working solid.

References:
http://www.tp-link.us/FAQ-190.html

dslreports dot com slash "faq/695"